# Audio-image merging

Tags: audio, video, images

I want to generate a video file taking an image and audio file as an input. I want this video file to be of the same duration as the audio file(stretching the still image for the whole duration). 
Do you know of any such application that can do this for me?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of slide show programs which do exactly as you describe. The interface presents itself as a film strip onto which you drop an image. Selecting the properties for the image allows you to configure the desired display time.

Integrated into the film strip is an audio track. The same drag and drop (or browse) is used to place your audio. The better programs will have a menu option to match the video duration to the audio.

You do not state platform for use, so I suggest a search with your favorite search engine for slide show software (insert platform name). You will receive results for both free programs and paid versions.

One paid version with which I have some experience is Pro Show Gold. Very easy to use, multiple output formats, but Windows only, to the best of my knowledge.

Alternatively, you could use a video editor. Many such programs offer slide show options which work the same way. A free program of this nature is Kdenlive, available for Windows and Linux. I've used it for both platforms and found that the Linux version is more stable, although that aspect may have been improved with a recent update.

Kdenlive is not as easy to use as the above noted slideshow software, but it is not particularly difficult to understand. Tutorial videos abound on YouTube for various functions, making the challenging stuff easier.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but almost all slideshow presentation softwares ask to add more than one image

Comment: A video editing program may perform better in that respect, although I don't recall having problems with Pro Show Gold for single image slideshows. "I don't recall" is not an absolute, however, as my brain cells don't always cooperate.